# Mongoose $sort doesn't work when it's before a populate stage in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, populate

I have the following Author schema, where an author can rate other authors:

```js
{
  name: String,
  birthDate: Date,
  otherAuthorRatings: {
    type: 
      [
        {
          author: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Author",
          },
          rating: {
            type: Number,
          },
        },
      ],
  }
}
```

I have an aggregation pipeline in which I'm populating the `author` property in the `otherAuthorRatings`, which goes through 3 stages, `unwind`, `lookup` and `group` according to [this documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/?_ga=2.13837431.1501732867.1671777053-750120624.1659257183#unwind-embedded-arrays).

Along with this, I want to `sort` the authors based on their `birthDate`, `skip` some elements and `limit` to a particular number of elements.

My question:-
When I add the sort, skip and limit stages after the population stage, the query works perfectly, but the $sort stage does not work correctly(i.e., returns random values instead of sorted values) when the sort, skip and limit stages are before the populate stage.

I specifically want that the sort, skip and limit stages be before the populate stage because I want to limit the populate stage to certain number of documents and also to use an index(which I cannot use if the sort stage is after the unwind, lookup and group stages).

Is there a particular reason why this happens? Any solution to this?

**EDIT 1:-**
I'm trying to sort the outer document, not the properties within the populated entries. Sample docs:-

```js
{ 
  _id: 1,
  name: "foo", 
  birthDate: "2022-12-24T00:00:00.000+00:00",
  otherAuthorRatings: [
    {
      author: 3,
      rating: 5
    }
  ], 
}, 
{ 
  _id: 2,
  name: "bar", 
  birthDate: "2022-12-25T00:00:00.000+00:00",
  otherAuthorRatings: [
    {
      author: 1,
      rating: 4
    },
    {
      author: 3,
      rating: 5
    },
  ], 
},
{ 
  _id: 3
  name: "baz", 
  birthDate: "2022-12-26T00:00:00.000+00:00",
  otherAuthorRatings: [], 
},
```

I want that the author with the birthdate of 24th December arrive before the author with the birthdate of 25th December and 26th December(or reverse if I sort it in descending order). I don't use the populated fields within the embedded document for sorting.

Solution:
Turns out that the `group` stage messes with the order(I believe this is normal) of transactions. So I had to re-sort the result after the group stage. This wasn't very costly because the sort was happening on a limited number of elements.

Comment: You can't sort before retrieving ('populating') the values if they aren't present in the document. And can you clarify what behavior you want coming from the sort? Are you trying to sort the `otherAuthorRatings` entries within the array for each document or sort the documents relative to each other based on the arrays? Perhaps some sample documents and desired output would help clarify

Comment: I'm trying to sort the outer document, not the properties within the populated entries. Sample docs:-
{ 
  name: "foo",
  birthDate: "2022-12-24T00:00:00.000+00:00"
  otherAuthorRatings: [],
},
{
  name: "bar",
  birthDate: "2022-12-25T00:00:00.000+00:00"
  otherAuthorRatings: [],
}

I want that the author with the birthdate of 24th December arrive before the author with the birthdate of 25th December(or vice-versa if I sort it in descending order).
I don't use the populated fields within the embedded document for sorting, I would just like the resultant documents to be populated.

Comment: I see, thanks for the details. Can you share the full command that you are running? Seems like it should be fine. As an aside - it's generally not advisable to store dates as strings

Comment: Ah no, I am storing it as a date object, the ones in the question were just for clarity.

Comment: Turns out that the `group` stage messes with the order(I believe this is normal) of transactions. So I had to re-sort the result after the group stage. This wasn't very costly because the sort was happening on a limited number of elements.

Comment: Right - this is why it would have been helpful to share the full command that you were executing. The top of [the $group documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) has an explicit note that "_`$group` does not order its output documents._" In general, any "streaming" stages (such as `$addFields`) will preserve document ordering while others (such as `$group`) will not. Thanks for following up.